# Diificulty in Retrieving all the data from SQLite database in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to learn how to store and retrieve data from SQLite database in android. I am successful in creating a database and also storing data in it but when I try to retrieve data Either I get only the data present in row=1,coln=1 or I don't get any data at all

There are 16 rows in my table and two column named ("**Name**", "**Nick_name**")

Here is my DBhelper class

```
public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


public DbHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, "Honey.db", null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {

    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("create table random (name text,Nick_name text)");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("drop table if exists random");
    onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);

 }
}
```

Here is my main.java

```
package com.honey.sqlite;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

DbHelper Db = new DbHelper(this);
DbHelper RDb = new DbHelper(this);


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            EditText Name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
            EditText Nick = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);


            SQLiteDatabase db = Db.getWritableDatabase();

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put("name", Name.getText().toString());
            values.put("Nick_name", Nick.getText().toString());

            long row = db.insert("random", null, values);

            System.out.println("ROW NUMBER IS = " + row);

            db.close();


            SQLiteDatabase rdb = RDb.getReadableDatabase();
            String array1[] = {"name", "Nick_name"};

            Cursor c = rdb.query("random", array1, null, null, null, null, null);



            //Cursor C = rdb.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM random",null);

            c.moveToFirst();

           while(!c.isAfterLast())
           {
               Log.e("value",c.getString(1));
               c.moveToNext();


           }



           Log.e("END FLAG","End");

           rdb.close();








        }
    });



  }
}
```

instead of looping over cursor if I use the commands below, I get the value stored in coln=1 row=1 that's it and get an error when trying to access next value

```
  Log.e("value",c.getString(1));
            Log.e("value",c.getStrong(2));
```

I need to retrieve all the data stored in 16 rows, Any help appreciated!

Comment: https://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Comment: `Log.e("value",c.getStrong(2));` getStrong instead of `getString()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to specify columns, as null will get all, equivalent to `SELECT *`.

```
Cursor c = rdb.query("random",null,null,null,null,null,null);
```

The simplest loop to get all rows from a Cursor is :-

```
while (c.moveToNext) {
    Log.d("YOURTAG","name is " + 
            c.getString(csr.getColumnIndex("name")) + 
            "Nickname is " + 
            c.getString(csr.getColumnIndex("Nick_name")) 
            + "ROW NUMBER is " + 
            String.valueOf(csr.getPosition())
    );
}
rdb.close();
```

using `getColumnIndex` means you don't have to worry about calculating offsets (or miscalucating them in your case as 0 is the first column (name)).

Note the offsets are according to the Cursor not the underlying table (although they are in the case of using null for the 2nd parameter)

Note if the Cursor is empty, then nothing (from the above) will be written to the log.

Comment: does c.getString(1) return an values present in entrie column =1?

Comment: @HoneyKhandelwal nope it returns a single column, the 2nd column. 0 is the first column.